# Add a title <li> before the first <li> of a dropdown with Wordpress Nav-walker class

Tags: wordpress, wp-nav-walker

I am trying to add a new `<li>` before the first `<li>` (or `<div>`) of the bootstrap dropdown, which will be the title of the dropdown. I know there should be a condition on the $output but what should I target to output only before the first `<li>` of a dropdown?

Code so far (inside `start_el()` function)-

```
if($depth == 1) {

        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;


        // The output to be filtered with condition
        $item_output .= '<div class="dropdown-item dropdown-title">DROPDOWN TITLE</div>';


        $item_output .= '<a class="dropdown-item" '. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

}
```

Output getting echoed before each `<li>`. Screenshot-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If that is in the `start_lvl` method, then I don't think there is any argument that will help you out. But you can just add a static var and set this to `false` once the first item has been handled if you want..

Might not be the cleanest solution, but if you don't find another simple solution, then it might do the trick for you.

```
static $isDropdownTitleRendered = false; // Static variable so the value stays remembered during the request
if ($depth == 1) {
        // First part of your code
        // ...

        // The output to be filtered with condition
        if (!$isDropdownTitleRendered) {
                $item_output .= '<div class="dropdown-item dropdown-title">DROPDOWN TITLE</div>';
                $isDropdownTitleRendered = true;
        }

        // ...
        // Rest of your code
}
```

Comment: So you think there is no clean or WP-way to solve this issue? How do they create mega-menu with titles and everything? Just asking.

Comment: @RPMcMurphy Personally, I would not use the WP Nav-Walker myself for a complex menu. I would instead render it myself. I often use Sage combined with Blade templating and then I simply create a Blade partial that handles my menu. I'm sure there are many other ways of achieving the same though.

Comment: Is there any tutorial you can direct me to achieve it? It's not much complex in terms of HTML, just a one level deep drop-down with a TTITLE on top of the drop-down. Hence trying to achieve it with custom nav-walker.

Comment: I meant you can either write code to render the menu yourself the way you want, or you can use the WP Nav-Walker. You could of course replace the static variable by a class variable as well if you think that is cleaner. I'm not sure if there are any other/better solutions either. Good luck!

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks much.